# Finding corners of a box given width, height, x and y

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

I have a React project, where i want to calculate x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinates based on given attributes x, y, width, height.

Below is an illustration of the data, that i have been given, and what i want to calculate:

The data i have is as follows: 
For the actual image`imageWidth, imageHeight` (in pixels),
For the Bounding Boxes: `x, y, width, height (in pixels)`

[image]

according to the image i would have the following data:

`{trueX: 133.09137618414758, trueY: 544.7949852507375, true Width: 1609.1268436578168, true Height: 320.3960746395861}`

according to this data, how could i convert it to to top left, and the bottom right corner of the box with a format like follows: `x1, x2, y1, y2`

Comment: Pixel cannot handle fractions, so you'd have to round your data somehow first. then take x, y as top left corner, and just add the length of x and y as appropriate to get the bottom right corner.

Comment: @TimB how can this be achieved in a Javascript function?